# error ACM (AWS) and cloudflare for validate a certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name               = "atlantis.mydomain"
  validation_method         = "DNS"

}
data "cloudflare_zones" "this" {
  filter {
    name   = "myzone.com"
    status = "active"
    paused = false
  }
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "cert_validation" {
  zone_id  = data.cloudflare_zones.this.zones[0].id
  name     = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type     = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  value    = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value
  ttl      = 3600
  proxied  = false
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [cloudflare_record.cert_validation.hostname]

}
```

1 error occurred:
* missing atlantis.mydomain DNS validation record: _1002e16ebd84cda6c12a865cf899175a.atlantis.mydomain

i don't know how to resolve this error

i have a problem when i want create a certificat ACM and validate with cloudflare  in aws and with terraform.

i have an error during the deployment about dns vérification
the record and the certificate have been created , but not validate
my cloudflare module is working well and for months

Comment: it's not literally 'mydomain' right?

Comment: Please can you edit your question so that it forms a [mcve]? While it should be minimal it should also be complete so that people can run it. Right now there's a whole bunch of missing stuff from your question including the creation of the ACM certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the values from the Terraform `aws_acm_certificate` resource's `domain_validation_options` values to create validation DNS records in CloudFlare. These will be entirely separate from the DNS record you are creating to point to your load balancer.

Comment: resource "cloudflare_record" "cert_validation" {
  zone_id  = data.cloudflare_zones.this.zones[0].id
  name   = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type     = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  value    = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value
  ttl      = 3600
  proxied  = false